# adding <iostream> breaks the code in g++-7

Tags: c++

There is sample

```
// Example 2: Will this compile? 
//
// In some library header:
namespace N { class C {}; }
int operator+(int i, N::C) { return i+1; }
// A mainline to exercise it:
#include <numeric>
int main()
{
  N::C a[10];
  std::accumulate(a, a+10, 0);
}
```

From "Exceptional C++: 47 Engineering Puzzles, Programming Problems, and Solutions"  -- Item 34. Name Lookup and the Interface Principle—Part 4

g++ 5.4 compiles it successfully.
But adding `#include <iostream>` breaks the code

```
// Example 2: Will this compile? 
//
// In some library header:
namespace N { class C {}; }
int operator+(int i, N::C) { return i+1; }
// A mainline to exercise it:
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    N::C a[10];
    std::accumulate(a, a+10, 0);
}
```

clang-4.0 is able to compile it. g++ 5.4 and g++7.2.0 show he following error

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/numeric:62:0,
                 from src/widget.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_numeric.h: In instantiation of ‘_Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp) [with _InputIterator = N::C*; _Tp = int]’:
src/widget.cpp:12:35:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_numeric.h:127:18: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘int’ and ‘N::C’)
  __init = __init + *__first;
           ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

Looks like bug in g++. I'm interested to know if workaround exists?

Comment: Workaround: put the operator in the namespace `N` and rely on ADL to find it

Comment: @Rakete1111 https://godbolt.org/g/3sCFDt

Comment: @Rakete1111 I'm using clang version 4.0.0-1ubuntu1~16.04.2 (tags/RELEASE_400/rc1)

Comment: @Rakete1111 - confirmed  - if I move it up clang fails to find proper operator - it is not listed in the candidates list

Comment: Just a guess, can it be that g++ <iostream> redefines the `+`operator? If so, put your definition inside the class C.

Comment: Well putting the operator inside namespace - resolves the error...  And it was solution suggested in the book. I have read further and found that observed behavior to be expected... Not that I understand the reasoning behind it... I probably will need to reread the explanation several times...

Comment: Interestingly, `clang++ -stdlib=libc++` reports a similar error, but `clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++` compiles the code successfully. Why is this so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IF somebody as curios as me - I'm posting what I have understood from further reading in the book.

Compiler will look for operator+ called from std::accumulate starting with namespace std.

Only if no candidates found in the namespace - it will go up and look for global namespace candidates.

So original sample and modified sample in clang were compiled by pure luck that no operator+ was declared before std::accumulate.

As soon as new header was added to the game - compiler stopped to look into the global namespace and stopped seeing proper operator as candidate at all.

Best match was not so good and cause all this strange error messages.

Now moving operator+ into namespace N was initiating Koenig lookup - if one of the function arguments is in the namespace N - suitable candidates should be looked in this namespace as well as addition to regular lookup.

Comment: How do you explain that having `#include <numeric>` does not expose the issue, but `#include <iostream>` does?

Comment: @Ripi2 it mean there is no operator+ declared in this header in the current implementation, and iostream has a lot of candidates for operator+ - they are listed in the full error message. But not one is suitable to the code