# type alias and operator<< overloading with ostream_iterator results in invalid operands

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I'm trying to understand why I can use an ostream_iterator for `Edge1` but not for `Edge` in the following code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>                  // for std::cout
#include <utility>                   // for std::pair

using VertexName = uint32_t;
using Edge = std::pair<VertexName, VertexName>;

struct Edge1 : public Edge {
    Edge1(VertexName x, VertexName y) : Edge(x,y) {};
};

std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Edge& e) {
    os << "(" << e.first << ", " << e.second << ")";
    return os;
}

int main(int,char*[])
{
    auto e1 = Edge(4,5);
    auto e2 = Edge1(5,6);
    std::cout << e1 << ", " << e2 << std::endl;
    auto it = std::ostream_iterator<Edge1>(std::cout, ", ");
    //*it++ = e1;
    *it++ = e2;
}
```

```

Although I can print out both `e1` and `e2` using the overloaded `operator<<(std::stream& os, const Edge& e)` function, I get the following error from clang-5.0 if I try to change the ostream_iterator to `std::stream_iterator<Edge>(std::cout, ", ")` and uncomment the `*it++ = e1` line.

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream_type' (aka 'basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >') and 'const std::__1::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>')
            *__out_stream_ << __value_;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~
/main.cpp:25:11: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::ostream_iterator<std::__1::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator=' requested here
    *it++ = e1;
```

Comment: Possibly the same thing happening as here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46163095/1896169

Comment: I'm not certain, so I'm not posting this as an answer, but I believe what is happening is that inside the `std` namespace, there is an `operator<<` already defined. The `ostream_iterator` is defined to call `operator<<` (`os << value`). However, this definition is inside the `std` namespace. Since your `operator<<` isn't found through ADL, it prefers to call one of the `operator<<` in the `std` namespace, thus never discovers the `operator<<` you defined in the global namespace

Comment: @Justin: I think that's about right. With `Edge` alias `std::pair<T, U>` as the type known to the iterator, both arguments to `<<` come from namespace `std`, so ADL only looks there (and fails, in the sense of finding the wrong candidate and quitting). With `Edge1` there is an argument from the global namespace, so it also looks there (and succeeds).

Comment: Although I had searched, looks like there was an answer to this question previously, shown here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/24110928/3762463

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Edge` is not a type it's a type alias of `std::pair`.

And of course ADL is not finding the overload of `operator<<` for `Edge` because it's defined in the wrong namespace... and you're not allowed to inject an overload in the std namespace.

The workaround is:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>                  // for std::cout
#include <utility>                   // for std::pair
#include <iterator>                   // for std::ostream_iterator

using VertexName = uint32_t;

// Edge is now a type, in the global namespace...
struct Edge : std::pair<VertexName, VertexName> {
    using std::pair<VertexName, VertexName>::pair;
};

struct Edge1 : public Edge {
    Edge1(VertexName x, VertexName y) : Edge(x,y) {};
};

// ...and this operator<< is defined in the global namespace so
// ADL will now find it.
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Edge& e) {
    os << "(" << e.first << ", " << e.second << ")";
    return os;
}

int main(int,char*[])
{
    auto e1 = Edge(4,5);
    auto e2 = Edge1(5,6);
    std::cout << e1 << ", " << e2 << std::endl;
    auto it = std::ostream_iterator<Edge>(std::cout, ", ");
    *it++ = e1;
    *it++ = e2;
}
```

Comment: Is there a need for `Edge1` any more?

Comment: @RSahu probably not in fairness.

Comment: Yes, this works great for me.  Also the first time I've run into inheriting constructors with the `using std::pair<VertexName, VertexName>::pair`