# Extending the functionality of std::vector<uint8_t> - namespace, composition or inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, composition

Very often I need to provide a `uint8_t` array to some third-party library. Usually the third-party library asks for a `uint8_t*`, together with a length argument. Generally I use a `std::vector<uint8_t>` and use its `data()` and `size()` methods to get this information which works a treat. Now I've often found myself wanting to create this `vector<uint8_t>` using the `<<` operator, similar to how `std::stringstream` works, for example:

```
uint8_t first = 8;
uint8_t second = 3;

std::vector<uint8_t> raw;
raw << first
    << second;
```

Often I need to mix integers of different sizes - a few one-byte header bytes, then one four-byte value, then a one-byte crc. This `<<` overload automatically takes care of this, for example:

```
uint32_t value = 0;

std::vector<uint8_t> raw;
raw << value;

int sz = raw.size(); // sz = 4
```

The `operator<<` function would look somewhat like the following. Keep in mind that in order to split up into individual bytes I'd either define multiple `operator<<` overloads, one for each type, or make a `std::is_arithmetic` restricted template. I'm not showing this for simplicity.

```
std::vector<uint8_t>& operator << (std::vector<uint8_t>& msg, uint8_t const& value)
{
    msg.push_back(value);
    return msg;
}
```

Now I obviously want to restrict this functionality. Not every `std::vector<uint8_t>` should have this functionality. One solution would be to define the `operator<<` in namespace `serial` and whenever the functionality is needed write `using namespace serial;` in the required scope. While not a bad solution, I still think this is a little confusing. In the same scope I may have a different `std::vector<uint8_t>` for which this functionality is not needed.

I'd ideally create a new type, `Message` which allows for this functionality so the code becomes:

```
Message msg1;
msg1 << 4; // OK, I've defined this
uint8_t* ptr1 = msg1.data(); // get pointer to first element - needs to be defined in the Message class.

std::vector<uint8_t> msg2;
msg2 << 4; // not OK, not part of std::vector<uint8_t>
uint8_t* ptr2 = msg2.data(); // get pointer to first element, fine as it's in std::vector
```

#### Composition

Now I could use composition to make this struct, like this:

```
struct Message
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> raw;
};
```

However that means that whenever you want to call a method of the vector (`size()`, `data()`, `begin()`, etc...) you need to call `msg.raw.size()`, `msg.raw.data()`, `msg.raw.begin()` which isn't particularly elegant (in my opinion). Obviously you can add functions to the Message struct that replicate the original functionality, like:

```
size_t size() const { return raw.size() };
size_t size() const noexcept { return raw.size() };
```

However given the size of std::vector that's a lot of functions, not to mention you'd have to change them when std::vector changes. I don't necessary need all functions that std::vector has to offer, but where to draw the line?

#### Inheritance

As far as I know - you do not, ever, inherit from standard types. Then I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46233041/type-alias-and-operator-overloading-with-ostream-iterator-results-in-invalid-o) answer by Richard Hodges, who seems to have a pretty good reputation, give this as a solution to a different question:

```
// Edge is now a type, in the global namespace...
struct Edge : std::pair<VertexName, VertexName> {
    using std::pair<VertexName, VertexName>::pair;
};
```

Does this mean I could do the following?

```
struct Message : std::vector<uint8_t> {
    using std::vector<uint8_t>::vector;
};

Message msg1;
msg1 << 8; // works (provided I define the operator<< as shown above for Message)
int sz = msg1.size(); // works as Message is a std::vector, result: 4

std::vector<uint8_t> msg2;
msg2 << 8; // doesn't work, as intended
```

What about if I want to add a variable to it, so it becomes:

```
enum class Endian
{
    lsb,
    msb
};

struct Message : std::vector<uint8_t>
{
    using std::vector<uint8_t>::vector;
    Endian m_endian;
};
```

Concrete question: can I do the second approach as it suits my needs best, or will I be in trouble as I inherit from std::vector? Any advice on the best approach would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I am having a little bit of a difficulty finding a specific, concrete question that's being asked here. Stackoverflow is for questions and answers, rather some general "advice".

Comment: See edit, last sentence. Thanks!

Comment: Sure yes - the first answer says "Yes it is OK to inherit from std::vector". Then a comment says "std::vector's destructor is not virtual, therefore you should never inherit from it". Then there's articles like https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/11/dont-inherit-from-std-types/ which also mentions that it's never OK to inherit from std::vector. I'm getting confused when it is OK, and when it is not OK to inherit from std::vector.

Comment: In order to clear up your confusion you need to learn and understand what all of the above means, and make an intelligent decision based on the totality of the information.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've used in the past for similar situations is to overload the `operator->` to give acces to the underlying object you want to wrap.

```
struct Message
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> raw;
    std::vector<uint8_t>* operator->() {
        return &raw;
    }
};
```

When you return a pointer from `operator->` that pointer will in turn also get dereferenced, so you can access any native vector functions using that.

```
Message m;
std::cout << m->data() << m->size();
```

And if you add your own methods you can access them as usual.

```
m.myOwnMethod();
```

You can also add your overloads of `operator<<` for `Message`.

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks! I think I'd get confused mixing `.` and `->` though, as I'd instantly think I'm dealing with a pointer when seeing a `->`.